# Return regex match in Yahoo Pipes

Tags: regex, yahoo-pipes

I want to take my 'item.title' string and store a match from a regular expression into 'item.myRegexMatch'. However, it's unclear to me how to achieve this, as all the Regex modules in YP require a "replacement" string. I don't want to replace anything; I just want the Regex match returned.
This seems trivial, but I'm fairly new with YP and regular expressions, so hopefully I'm simply overlooking this basic functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Quick answer :**

Steps :

1/ Rename module :

```
[item.title] COPY [item.myRegexMatch]
```

2/ Regex module :

```
in [item.myRegexMatch] replace [^.*(YOURREGEX).*] with [$1]
                                   ^         ^
```

be sure to keep the 2 parentheses indicated in the above line.

**Explaination :**

The parentheses in the "replace" field define a [backreference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html).

This backrefencere is then used ($1) in the "with" field.